# call another asynchtask inside onPostExecute()

Tags: android

I trying to call another Asynchtask inside my onPostExcute. Logcat says I've problem with the last line of the second asynch task. I can't find the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

LoginActivity has a method loginUser, which calls the first Asynchtask PostLoginData which inturn calls the second one called VitalService.

Logcat says problem is with last line of the 2nd asynctask

Here's the Code

LoginActivity

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.cinch.loginapp.MESSAGE";
    public static final String urlString = RestApiPaths.LOGIN;
    public static Context context;
    LoginActivity loginActivity;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        context = this.getBaseContext();

    }
    public void loginUser(View view) {
        EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_username);
        EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_password);
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        if (username != null && !username.isEmpty() && password != null && !password.isEmpty()) {
            PostLoginData postLoginData = new PostLoginData(LoginActivity.this);
            postLoginData.execute(urlString, username, password);
        }

    }
}
```

PostLoginData.java

```
public class PostLoginData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    public LoginActivity loginActivity;
    private Activity activity;
    private Context context;
    public PostLoginData(LoginActivity activity){
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = this.activity.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String username = params[1].toString();
        String password = params[2].toString();
        String message = null;
        HttpClient httpClient = ServiceHelper.getHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://test.gogch.com/gch-restful/login");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            Log.d("Http Post Response:" ,Integer.toString(statusCode));
            message = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.d("Http Post Response:" ,message);
        }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return message;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            String status = json.getString("status");
            if(status.equals("true"))
                new VitalService(activity).execute();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

VitalService

```
public class VitalService extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    public final static String VITAL_RESPONSE = "com.cinch.loginapp.VITALS";
    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;

    public VitalService(Activity activity){
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = this.activity.getApplicationContext();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){

        String vitalsResponseText = null;
        HttpClient httpClient = ServiceHelper.getHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://test.gogch.com/gch-restful/vitals/custome/added/parentvitals");
        Log.d("KMN", "Sucess");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            vitalsResponseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return vitalsResponseText;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String responseText){

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, VitalListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(VITAL_RESPONSE,responseText);
        Log.d("putextra","success");
        context.startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

VitalListActivity

```
public class VitalListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static List<String> vitalList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_vital_list);
        Log.d("rfvb","ok");
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String status = intent.getStringExtra(VitalService.VITAL_RESPONSE);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(status);
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
04-08 18:17:30.028    3716-3716/com.cinch.getvitalsapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cinch.getvitalsapp, PID: 3716
    android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
            at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1232)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1219)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:322)
            at com.cinch.getvitalsapp.services.VitalService.onPostExecute(VitalService.java:65)
            at com.cinch.getvitalsapp.services.VitalService.onPostExecute(VitalService.java:28)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: This message is saying that you can are calling start activity from your second asynch task. And if you want to call from this place then you need to set flag in the manifest as FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it will work. Based on my idea

```
Intent i = new Intent().setClass(context, YourActivity.class);  
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);

// Launch the new activity and add the additional flags to the intent
context.startActivity(i);
```

Once i got same issue. I solved like this not sure about your case. Try this.

Comment: i added intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); and its working. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use your local field `activity` rather than `context` to start the new `Activity`.  It's flagging this as a problem because the `context` field is really an application context rather than an `Activity` context.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the applicationContext instead pass the activity.

public class VitalService extends AsyncTask {

```
    public final static String VITAL_RESPONSE = "com.cinch.loginapp.VITALS";
    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;

    public VitalService(Activity activity){
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = this.activity.getApplicationContext();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){

        String vitalsResponseText = null;
        HttpClient httpClient = ServiceHelper.getHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://test.gogch.com/gch-restful/vitals/custome/added/parentvitals");
        Log.d("KMN", "Sucess");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            vitalsResponseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return vitalsResponseText;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String responseText){
        if(activity == null){
         //please handle this state because it might happen
}
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, VitalListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(VITAL_RESPONSE,responseText);
        Log.d("putextra","success");
        activity.startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```